# Mac OS Catalina - Bluetooth audio output issues (WF-1000XM3, Bose QuietComfort 35)

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, catalina, bluetooth, headphones

I have new Macbook Pro 16' with Mac OS Catalina (obviously I can't downgrade)

From time to time, music stops playing inside the headphones (WF-1000XM3).
The headphones are still connected, but sound output switched from the headphones.
Changing sound output to the headphones will produce spinning wheel, but will not actually change it.

- Turning off and on the headphones sometimes fixes the issue.
- Resetting BT module temporary fixes the issue (SHIFT + OPTION + click on BT in menu bar)
  [image: Debug BT menu bar]

It's was really frustrating, How I fixed it is below.

Comment: I have these same headphones and they’ve been nothing but Bluetooth purgatory.  If there isn’t line of sight between the a Mac and the headphones, forget about reliable connections.  I switched to a Sennheiser M2 and solved all the issues immediately

Comment: Hey @Allan, Thank you for your comment. I agree with issues you mentioned, but the issue I mention happens even if you are literally next to the mac. It's Catalina specific and I wouldn't be surprised if it happens with all headphones.

Comment: I don’t think it’s Catalina specific because the issue existed on El Capitan as well.  I had no problem with my substantially cheaper Jaybird X4s.  Those worked perfectly but didn’t have the noise cancellation I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Forcing headphones to use aptX codec fixes the issue.

How to change it?

1. **Head to https://developer.apple.com/bluetooth/**
   [image: Apple developer website preview]
2. **Download additional tools for Xcode (you might need to sign in with your Apple ID)**
   [image: Downloads page on apple Developer Portal]
3. **Open downloaded image and open Hardware folder**
   [image: Downloaded additional tools]
4. **Move BT Explorer to your application folder and open it**
   [image: BT Explorer app]
5. **Select `Force use of aptX`**
   [image: BT Explorer app opened]
6. **Disconnect your headphones and connect again**
7. **Hold OPTION/ALT key and click on BT in the menu bar, find your headphones, it should show `Active Codec: AptX`**
   [image]
8. From my experience this should fix the issues.

**Edit:** Some people reported that disabling `Ask Siri` reduces the issues as well.